# Get all parent rows and each row followed by their child's rows

Tags: sql

I've two tables one of them called 
Main-Level
another one called 
Sub-level

Sub-level has a foreign key from the Main level (the relation between them Main-Level has one or Many Sub-levels )

what I want is to create a query to show the Main-level row followed by all Sub-level rows such as below screen-shot either by native SQL query or LINQ.

[image]

### **Update:**

---

I used below but the problem is it the result such as Full OUTer JOIN !

```
select * from Sublevel
right join Mainlevel
on Sublevel.mainlevelID=Mainlevel.id 
order by coalesce(Sublevel.mainlevelID, Mainlevel.id),
         (case when Sublevel.mainlevelID is null then 1 else 0 end),Mainlevel.id;
```

### Update 2:

---

Also, I tried below query but with no luck :

```
SELECT
    s.name,
    s.Id,
    CASE WHEN s.is_child = 1 THEN s.parentID END AS parent_id,
    m.name
FROM
    Mainlevel m
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, name, parentID, 1 AS is_child
    FROM Sublevel
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name,Null, 0 AS is_child
    FROM Mainlevel
    ) s on m.id = s.mainlevelID
ORDER BY  m.id,is_child, s.mainlevelID
```

**My problem in simple language  is How to make the child rows appeared below parent row**

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I don't understand what did you mean by sample table data (because I expressed what I want on Excell then I took the screen-shot from it )

Comment: I added a new query based on the query you made above. I found the field name inconsistency in your query so I am not sure whether the columns you specify here really exists in your table definition, but I just made a try and hope it works for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall plan is to have parent join (parent + child) order by (parent ID, child ID)

```
SELECT
    c.level_id,
    c.level_name,
    c.level_code,
    CASE WHEN c.is_child = 1 THEN c.parent_id END AS parent_id,
FROM
    mainLevel p
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT level_id, level_name, level_code, parent_id, 1 AS is_child
    FROM subLevel
    UNION ALL
    SELECT level_id, level_name, level_code, level_id, 0 AS is_child
    FROM mainLevel
    ) c on p.level_id = c.parent_id
ORDER BY p.level_id, is_child, c.level_id
```

Additional version to adopt to the newly clarified column availability

```
SELECT
    w.name,
    w.id,
    CASE WHEN w.is_child = 1 THEN w.mid END AS parent_id
FROM
    Mainlevel m
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, name, parentID AS mid, 1 AS is_child
    FROM Sublevel
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, id AS mid, 0 AS is_child
    FROM Mainlevel
    ) w on m.id = w.mid
ORDER BY  m.id, is_child, w.id
```

Comment: I will check it

Comment: it returns only the child rows I want parent row follows by their child's

Comment: @user3189162 it does return parent rows as well if you run it...the "c" subquery is parent union child.

Comment: it shows the parent rows alongside the child rows looks like FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: @user3189162 How can you see the parent rows alongside given my query only select 4 fields from child (the "c" subquery)? Did you pasted some wrong query to run?

Comment: the same query but I removed levelID column because I don't have levelID  in My question I meant by the screen shoot is how I would the result become . I will attach the query on the question now

Comment: what ID column do you have for the child? I thought your parent and child both share the same ID sequence so I used that as the FK to join...

Comment: "take union of parent + child" and sort by "is_child" is how I achieved the target to put child below parent.

Comment: I've in the child auto-generated ID and parent ID as an FK,Could you please check my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209387/discussion-between-user3189162-and-coy).

Comment: Please note that in your Excel output, your parentid 5 is placed below the MainLevel with levelID = 5 but not MainLevel2. This is the trigger to make most people think levelID is the PK...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by`:

```
order by coalesce(parentid, id),
         (case when parentid is null then 1 else 0 end),
         id
```

Comment: Did you mean add this after the inner join between the parent and child table

Comment: @user3189162 . . . No, you can just order the table you have shown.

Comment: The table that I've shown is the result that I want to get not what I have